# Extracting sender and date sent from .eml file using applescript

Tags: email, applescript

I am using drag and drop to pull emails from Mail into their relevant job sub-folders on a shared server. Then I am using a script to sort by date created (this is the date I have dragged them across) and then renaming the file based on the name of it's container.

However I would like to use a script to extract the date sent, the sender and the subject from each .eml file, and then use that information to rename the file.

There was a previous post with an answer to a similar question however it was not clear to me (as I am a newbie to scripting) how it could be placed into my script. 
It can be found in:
"AppleScript - Get information of .eml file"

the answer was:

```
set fromField to text 7 thru -1 of (do shell script "cat /test.eml | grep From:")
set dateField to text 7 thru -1 of (do shell script "cat test.eml | grep Date:")
set toField to text 5 thru -1 of (do shell script "cat /test.eml | grep To:")
set subjectField to text 10 thru -1 of (do shell script "cat /test.eml | grep Subject:")
```

I think I need someone to write the actual shell script and tell me where to place it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
    set delim to " - "

set myFiles to (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
set TID to text item delimiters

repeat with aFile in myFiles
    set pFile to quoted form of (POSIX path of aFile)
    set {mDate, mFrom, mSubject} to every paragraph of (do shell script "cat " & pFile & " | grep -e Date -e From: -e Subject:")

    set mDate to trim(mDate, 7)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
    set myDate to text item 3 of mDate & space & text item 2 of mDate & ", " & text item 4 of mDate
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    set myDate to (date myDate)
    set myDate to day of myDate & (month of myDate as integer) & year of myDate as text

    set mFrom to trim(mFrom, 7)
    set mSubject to trim(mSubject, 10)

    set newName to myDate & delim & mFrom & delim & mSubject

    -- You will have to edit newName so it meets file naming standards
    --tell application "System Events" to set aFile's name to mSubject
end repeat
set text item delimiters to TID

on trim(myText, firstChar)
    try
        set myText to text firstChar thru -1 of myText
    on error
        set myText to "None"
    end try
end trim
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for your help. I tried the script and it is getting to the information. However when I added a line to rename aFile to newName it came up with a stack overflow error. Also is there a way to get the date into ddmmyyyy format?

Comment: See edit for date format. You need to manipulate newName so it meets file naming standards to avoid the errors.

Comment: I am getting a Finder error: can't continue trim at the first trim(mDate,7). If I remove all the trims it will rename the file (lots of text) but the subject is missing. All your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions, that would make your script just less than 10 lines and much easier to read.

Granted AppleScript does not support regular expressions natively, you just need to install the Satimage Osax extension at http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html